# Get all items from a dynamic made nav in Alfresco for Selenium WebDriver with Java

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, selenium

**Topic** 
How can i get all text from nav items from a dynamic(JS) made nav. 
I need it for a Selenium WebDriver script (Java).

**Situation HTML**

```
    <!--//Dynamic generated JS nav menu-->
<div ID="has_special_id_that i_use_to_select"> 

    <!--1 item of the nav menu with no subitem-->
    <div>
        <span>
            <a>I can get this text and echo to Eclipse console</a>
        </span>
    </div>

<!--    // 1 item of the nav menu with subitem-->
<!--    //here there shoulde be also subitems only i can echo a ?-->
    <div>
        <span>Strange item</span>
        <span>
            <span>I can get this text and echo to Eclipse console</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am able to get all items(parent) only not the subitems(childeren)
Perhaps a JS problem because its a dynamic nav made with js.

**My Java code**

```
package myFirstSeleniumTest;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class CheckNavAlf {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String baseUrl = "https://specifi.url.com";
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("uname");
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("pwd");
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).submit();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        List<WebElement> dropdowns = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='uniqName_1_4']/div/span"));
        if (dropdowns.size() >= 1) {

            for (WebElement dropdown : dropdowns) {
//System.out.println(dropdowns.size());
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(dropdown.getText());
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(dropdown.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Error in the code");
        }
//driver.quit();
    }
}
```

**My result**

```
Home
---------------------------------------
<a tabindex="-1" title="Home" href="/share/page/site/kennis-databank/wiki-page?title=Main_Page" class="alfresco-navigation-_HtmlAnchorMixin">Home</a>
---------------------------------------
---------------------------------------
My Files
---------------------------------------
<a tabindex="-1" title="My Files" href="/share/page/context/mine/myfiles" class="alfresco-navigation-_HtmlAnchorMixin">My Files</a>
---------------------------------------
---------------------------------------
Shared Files
---------------------------------------
<a tabindex="-1" title="Shared Files" href="/share/page/context/shared/sharedfiles" class="alfresco-navigation-_HtmlAnchorMixin">Shared Files</a>
---------------------------------------
---------------------------------------
Sites
---------------------------------------
<span id="HEADER_SITES_MENU_text" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode,textDirNode">Sites</span>
---------------------------------------
---------------------------------------
? <= sub menu items, only ? but no content
---------------------------------------
? <= sub menu items, only ? but no content
---------------------------------------
---------------------------------------
Tasks
---------------------------------------
<span id="HEADER_TASKS_text" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode,textDirNode">Tasks</span>
---------------------------------------
---------------------------------------
? <= <= sub menu items, only ? but no content
---------------------------------------
? <= <= sub menu items, only ? but no content
---------------------------------------
---------------------------------------
People
---------------------------------------
<a tabindex="-1" title="People" href="/share/page/people-finder" class="alfresco-navigation-_HtmlAnchorMixin">People</a>
---------------------------------------
```

Comment: Are the dropdown submenu's visible in the html before opening?

Comment: @Mobrockers => hi when I open this page on the top left there is this nav.
The submenu items are not visible yet. If I want to see them, I need to click on this particular nav item. After I did that I can see a list dropping down with links to other parts in Alfresco

Answer (score 0):

To open submenus in my tests I use this method:

```java
@Override
public Page clickContextMenuSubItem(ActionsMenuItem... items) {

    ActionsMenuItem child = items[0];
    // Hover over every next parent until we're out of parents
    for (ActionsMenuItem nextParent : items) {

        child = nextParent.moveTo();
    }

    child.click();

    LOGGER.log(Level.TRACE, "Context menu sub item clicked");

    return this;
}
```

My `ActionsMenuItem` encapsulates my WebElements but basically it does

```java
new Actions(driver).moveToElement('My-Element').pause(1).perform();
```

In my case hovering is enough to open the submenus. If you need to click on the submenu items before they open you can use this instead

```java
new Actions(driver).moveToElement('My-Element').pause(1).click().perform();
```

Does this help you enough?

Comment: i will check your solution only one question about your function => public Page clickContextMenuSubItem(ActionsMenuItem... items)

Comment: Why do you write (ActionsMenuItem... items) <= why the ... after ActionsMenuItem? What can you do with it

Comment: No I ask the wrong question => Do I need the put my List<WebElement> dropdowns as a parameter in this clickContextMenuSubItem(ActionsMenuItem... items) method  so which type should this parameter be en which type should the ActionsMenuItem child = items[0]; be both List<WebElement>?

Comment: ActionsMenuItem would be WebElement and ActionsMenuItem... would be List<WebElement> without (...). the (...) means that you can pass variable arguments to the method, or an array, which I use for my method but is not needed for yours. You also cannot to item[0] if you use a List<> but you can do list.get(0).